# Confusion about CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been using CTE for a long time, but I have a question about how a CTE works.

1. With CTE executed once per query or once per row? (means it will execute first and then pass the result to the lower part or it executes one row and pass to lower part of query)
2. As we know CTE is executed in memory and what happen when we use the same CTE in same query twice? Is that it will use the same result from memory or will again calculate it?

Comment: You are asking for a tutorial or documentation which is off-topic on SO.

Comment: At least tag dbms used. How could we know how an unknown product works...?

Comment: This is something related to sql. So i add tag as sql

Comment: start here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Most RDBMS use **SQL** as their query language, but the technical details about how certain things work might differ between `mysql`, `postgresql`,  `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2` and others - so therefore we **need to know** which **concrete database system** you're using to provide meaningful responses. Therefore, please **add a relevant** tag

Comment: My question is related to SQL Server :)

Answer (score 1):

A CTE is mainly for us to have our queries structured for better readability.

This query:

```
with blue_items as (select * from items where color = 'blue')
   , lightblue_items as (select * from blue_items where tone = 'pale')
select *
from lightblue_items;
```

is the same as

```
select *
from (select * from (select * from items where color = 'blue') where tone = 'pale');
```

only differently written. It is up to the DBMS how to execute it. It can even re-write the query internally to

```
select * from items where color = 'blue' and tone = 'pale';
```

Same with a self-join. How the DBMS executes the following query is again up to the DBMS. It will try to find the best execution plan, which *could* mean to read the table twice *or* to read it once and operate on it in memory instead.

```
with cte as (select * from persons)
select *
from cte p1
join cte p2 on p2.personid <> p1.personid;
```

Don't worry about this. Write your queries so that you find them readable and rely on the DBMS to do its job properly and find the best execution method.

Comment: *Don't worry about this. Write your queries so that you find them readable and rely on the DBMS to do its job properly and find the best execution method.* Don't worry until your DB decides to select a totally wrong execution plan :-) With very complex cte (and queries) it can happen :-(

Comment: @xanatos: Okay, then I make it "worry when it's time to worry" ;-)